# Using Active Record on object split across two tables in codeigniter

Tags: php, database, activerecord, codeigniter

I have a controller that is represented in the database by two tables, `pages` and `page_contents`.  `pages` contains the author information, unique id for the the page, and creation timestamp.  `page_contents` contains the page uid as a FK, the contents of the page, last editor, and edit timestamp.

When a page it requested I need to pull the original author and creation timestamp, the contents of the most recent revision of the page contents.

How would I do this using active record methods?  Or will I have to use $this->db->query(() and a handcrafted SQL statement?

Comment: what database? Question is marked database. Please modify tags appropriately so they match your question.

Comment: It shouldn't matter what database.  I am asking about the database abstraction layer of Codeigniter, so it would apply no matter what database I am using.  So I didn't include any specific database tags, gust the general database tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the join ($this->db->join();) methods provided by the [active record library](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html) to specify how to connect the two tables but if you're looking for more ORM style retrieval try the [Doctrine Library for Codeigniter](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/cookbook/code-igniter-and-doctrine/en) I'm not 100% sure if it will support it but it's what frameworks like symfony use to get this behavior.

The new version of Codeigniter (2.0) will include a more ORM style model retrieval. ORM is one of the big reasons for [Kohana](http://kohanaframework.org/) (a fork of Codeigniter) that actually includes try active record.

Comment: An alternative to Doctrine is the Datamapper Overzealous library created for Codeigniter - http://www.overzealous.com/dmz/

Comment: @someoneinomaha have you had any experience with it? what's your opinion?

Comment: I've been using it on a project that I've been working on (on off hours) for about a year now. I really like it for the most part. There are a few things that seem odd - if you view the profiler, you'll see it do a select @ from table limit 1 whenever you instantiate a new object... but if you turn caching on, it no longer has to do that.